ubuntu 24.04 could not load kernal32 dll
Installed debian wine on ubuntu 24.04
Tried to configure in terminal using   winecfg
got reply  wine: could not load kernal32.dll, status c0000135

This question is similar to: Cant install wine32 on Ubuntu 23.04. If you believe it’s different, please edit the question, make it clear how it’s different and/or how the answers on that question are not helpful for your problem.
